# How to get the view controller wrapped by a UIPopoverController from UIStoryboardPopoverSegue?

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, xcode-storyboard

I have an UISplitViewController with the master having an UIViewController embedded in an UINavigationController. A toolbar button is responsible for bringing an UIPopoverController up, via segue. Such popover controller wraps an UIViewController also embedded in an UINavigationController, called SettingsViewController.

I can get a pointer to the UIPopoverController from the UIStoryboardPopoverSegue:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(UITableViewCell *)sender
{
  if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Settings"]) {
    UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *popoverSegue = (UIStoryboardPopoverSegue*) segue;

    SettingsViewController *settingsViewController = ... // TODO
    settingsViewController.popoverController = popoverSegue.popoverController;
  }
}
```

But I can't find a way to get a reference to the inner SettingsViewController. I don't want to use a static field accessible via class method, it would be a terrible workaround.

What am I missing to get it right?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UIPopoverSegue contains a UIPopoverController

```
UIPopoverController *popoverController = popoverSegue.popoverController;
```

With this you can easily get the contentViewController (view displayed in the popover)

```
UINavigationController *contentNC = (UINavigationController *) popoverController.contentViewController;
```

And from the content navigation controller, you get the actual view controller:

```
SettingsViewController *settingsVC = [contentNC.viewControllers lastObject];
```

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: That looks like it's going to get him to the pop over's content controller, which it sounds like is going to be a UINavigationController in this case. He's still going to need to unwind that one more hop and grab the UINavigation controller's root view controller.

Comment: Exactly, I've just added that to Lukas' answer. It works perfectly now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have a very similar setup in my app as described at the beginning of the question.

In my `prepareForSegue` (and inside where I check the `segue.identifier`) I grab and set things on the popover's view controller like so:

```
settingsViewController *settingsPop = segue.destinationViewController;
settingsPop.someVar = self.var;
```

`segue.destinationViewController` makes it simple and easy.